# Url change but not rendering component React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi i am trying to change the route of my website to go to Contact, when the menu is clicked.
Whenever i press the button for the homepage which is "Forside", the routing works perfectly.

But as soon as i press the button for the contact which is "Kontakt", the url changes and no component renders. But if i refresh the page, it shows up..

Any ideas what is wrong with my code, or any way to fix it?
All help will be appreciated thanks.

My App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Forside from './forside';
import Kontakt from './Kontakt';
import Header from './Header'

const App = () => {
return(
<Router>
<div>
<Header/>
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Forside}/>
<Route path="/kontakt" component={Kontakt}/>
</Switch>
</div>
</Router>
)
}

export default App
```

And this is where i link to the different routes.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './header.css'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import BottomNavigation from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation';
import BottomNavigationAction from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigationAction';
import ContactMailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ContactMail';
import LocationOnIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocationOn';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 500,
  },
});

const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

return(
<div className="hed">
<h1 className="logo"><span>IT</span> ARBEJDE.DK</h1>

<BottomNavigation
  value={value}
  className="nav"
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  showLabels
  className={classes.root}
>
  <Link to="/">
  <BottomNavigationAction label="Søg job" icon={<LocationOnIcon />} />
  </Link>

<Link to="/kontakt">
<BottomNavigationAction label="Kontakt" icon={<ContactMailIcon/>} />
</Link>
  

</BottomNavigation>
</div>     
)
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i didn't get a answer, i have figured it out on my own. So i would just like to share the solution, for other people who maybe are expecting the same bug.

I fixed the problem, by restructuring my code.
I placed my router inside the index.js component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(

  <React.StrictMode>
       <Router>
           <App/>
       </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,

  
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then placed the Header code inside my App.js, instead of having the Component rendering.

So i refactored the code like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Kontakt from './Kontakt';
import Forside from './forside';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import BottomNavigation from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation';
import BottomNavigationAction from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigationAction';
import ContactMailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ContactMail';
import LocationOnIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocationOn';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './header.css'


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      width: 500,
    },
  });


const App = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

return(
<div>
<div className="header-container">
<h1 className="logo"><span>IT</span> ARBEJDE.DK</h1>
<BottomNavigation
  value={value}
  className="nav"
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  showLabels
  className={classes.root}
>
  <BottomNavigationAction label="Søg job" component={Link} to="/" icon={<LocationOnIcon />} />
  <BottomNavigationAction label="Kontakt" component={Link} to="/kontakt" icon={<ContactMailIcon/>} />
</BottomNavigation>
</div>     

<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Forside}/>
<Route exact path="/kontakt" component={Kontakt}/>
</Switch>
</div>
)
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

add exact to it to your route

```js
<Route exact path="/kontakt" component={Kontakt}/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this has already been suggested. But the person deleted their comment, this still doesen't have any effect on the program...